# Inbox notifications from Documentation are too numerous to be useful; please add a different notification system

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

Today I opened Stack Overflow, and I found that I had ***302*** notifications in my inbox:

[image]

I'm subscribed to notifications for edits for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) on Documentation. The current system of notifications does not work well for popular tags on Docs, since the notifications are too numerous and drown out other notifications, and I ended up turning them off. Setting the notifications to "Once a day" or one of the other less frequent options is also sub-optimal, since then, one does not get notified immediately.

I think it would be useful to add a different & separate system for notifications from Docs, perhaps something similar to the yellow bubble we see in the top bar for suggested edits, and perhaps make what it counts / shows customizable per-user:

[image]

Comment: What are your settings? The default is no alerts for anything and alert for when your flag has been handled. I have mine in 3 hours for improvement requests on git, 1 day for improvements and 1 week for topic requests.

Comment: +1 here. Keep getting useless notifications from documentation.